# How do I "Create an <h1> element and give it an ID, but don't put any text inside In JavaScript, select your <h1> element and give it some text'

Tags: javascript, html

create an `<h1>` element and give it an ID, but don't put any text inside
In JavaScript, select your `<h1>` element and give it some text

Answer (score 0):

To modify an existing element:

```js
let h1Node = document.querySelector('#myId');
h1Node.textContent = 'This is the text content!';
```

```html
<h1 id='myId'></h1>
```

Or, to create a new node and append it to the document:

```js
let h1Node = document.createElement('h1');
h1Node.id = 'myId';
h1Node.textContent = 'This is the text content!';
document.body.appendChild(h1Node);
```

Hope this helps,

Answer (score 0):

In your HTML file, you're going to create

```
<h1 id="idName"> </h1>
```

You want to create a JS file add it as a script to your html file.

```
<script src="myscripts.js"></script>
```

and then in your Javascript file, you're going to

```
let element = document.getElementById('idName');

element.innerHTML += 'text goes here';
```

Answer (score 0):

`<h1 id="example"></h1>`

Javascript:

```
function addText (text){
  document.getElementById('example').innerHTML = "hi";
}
```

call function wherever you want

Comment: When you answer a question, try to explain your question a little bit, even if right. In your case, there are additional answers so expose the Pros and Cons of your P.O.V.